# Error while installing PyNaCl on NAS with python

Tags: python, exception, pip, easy-install, nas

While trying to install a discord MusicBot on my nas I encountered a exception stating that easy_instal.py is not on the sys.path. See below for more details.

```
Collecting PyNaCl
Using cached PyNaCl-1.1.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 
416, in fetch_build_egg
    cmd = self._egg_fetcher
AttributeError: 'Distribution' object has no attribute '_egg_fetcher'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-8lwabom5/PyNaCl/setup.py", line 232, in <module>
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
  File "/opt/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 318, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 375, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1123, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 441, in fetch_build_egg
    cmd.ensure_finalized()
  File "/opt/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 315, in finalize_options
    d + " (in --site-dirs) is not on sys.path"
distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: /opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages (in --site-dirs) is not on sys.path

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8lwabom5/PyNaCl/
```

Now I was wondering how to solve this, I tried reinstalling easy_install and setting the sys.path manually but none of these solutions seemed to have worked so far. I'm kinda new to python and installing it on a nas so I would appreciate some help regarding this problem.

Some additional info:

- synology NAS dsplay216
- command used: sudo python3.5 -m pip install PyNaCl

Comment: What are the contents of /tmp/pip-build-8lwabom5/PyNaCl/ ?